# Can't see itunesconnect Sandbox Tester on physical device

Tags: flutter, app-store-connect

I'm following [**this**](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-in-app-purchases#3) guide to setup in app purchases for my Flutter app

On step 4, it tells me to create a Sandbox account which is **NOT** associated with an itunes account. I did that, but I can't find the sandbox tester section on my **Physical device**

**The first image is the guide's screen, the 2nd is mine**

[image]
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Note: I'm using IOS 15.7.7 if that matters.

Thanks!